# Should I use 1/2" or 3/4" fixtures for a new shower?

Tags: plumbing

I am having a new shower built along with a new bathroom altogether...

I selected Grohe hardware and wanted to know if I should go with the 1/2" or 3/4" since I will have a rain shower, hand held unit, and 4 jets.

Will I be able to have the plumber hook everything up with the existing 1/2" pipe or do I need to upgrade to 3/4"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would upgrade to the 3/4" pipe.  With as many fixtures as you have, you won't have good water pressure with more than one of them on at a time.

Comment: keep in mind that if you feed a 3/4 in line from a 1/2 inch line the effect will be negative.  The 3/4 must go back to the main line, as any 1/2 will be the limiting factor.